# Selecting certain columns from a table with dates as columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where column names are like years `"2020-05","2020-06", "2020-07"` etc and so many years as columns.I need to select only the current month, next month and third month columns alone from this table.`(DB : PostgreSQL Version 11)`

But since the column names are "TEXT" are in the format `YYYY-MM` , How can I select only the current month and future 2 months from this table without hard-coding the column names.

**Below is the table structure , Name : static_data**
[image]

Required select statement is like this,The table contains the 14 months data as in the above screen shot like DATES as columns.From this i want the current month , and next 2 month columns along with their data, something like below.

SELECT "2020-05","2020-06","2020-07" from static
-- SELECT Current month and next 2 months 
**Required output:**

[image]

Comment: I think that you need to use crosstab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query

Comment: You should really normalize your database design and store each date on a separate row. Your current structure makes simple tasks utterly complicated.

Comment: Table definitions and sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: What exactly is the contents of those columns? Don't you want to see that as well?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There are some text values, basically numbers in various formats like like 1000$, etc.. in those columns.Yes and i would need to see the data as well.That is what i was looking for.

Comment: Your screenshot that shows what you want, does not contain that information. I don't understand how exactly the output should look like you want. Please **[edit]** your question and add a complete example. Ideally with a `CREATE TABLE` statement and some insert statements to show the sample data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_nameEdited and attached screen shot both table and required output.Can we achieve like this.I need to select the current month and next 2 months columns from the table(There are 16 columns DATES as columns in the tABLE) from which i need to select the data from 3 columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Any suggestions on how to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nearly impossible to get the actual value of the current month as the column name, but you can do something like this:

```
select d.item_sku,
       d.status,
       to_jsonb(d) ->> to_char(current_date, 'yyyy-mm') as current_month,
       to_jsonb(d) ->> to_char(current_date + interval '1 month', 'yyyy-mm') as "month + 1",
       to_jsonb(d) ->> to_char(current_date + interval '2 month', 'yyyy-mm') as "month + 2"
from bad_design d
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for even though its an unnecessary complicated one,the baove one works fine and thanks a lot!! I will re-design it.

Comment: @Linu: it's "unnecessary complicated" because of your broken data model

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use the information schema to achieve this. But, like [GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61697901/selecting-certain-columns-from-a-table-with-dates-as-columns#comment109133361_61697901) said, please re-design your schema and do not approach this issue like this, in the first place.

The special schema [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html) contains meta-data about your DB. Among these is are details about existing [columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html). In other words, you can query it and convert their names into dates to compare them to what you need.
Here are a few hints.

Query existing column names.

```sql
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
  AND table_name   = 'your_table'
```

Compare two dates.

```sql
SELECT now() + INTERVAL '3 months' < now() AS compare;
```

```
 compare                                                       
---------
 f
(1 row)
```

You're already pretty close with the conversion yourself.

Have fun and re-design your schema!

Comment: I need the data as well, Something like this "SELECT Curent_month,Next_month,third_month FROM static_data"

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this does not answer your question - but it's too long for a comment.

You need to fix the design of this table. Instead of storing dates in columns, you should have each date on a *separate row*.

There are numerous drawbacks to your current design:

- very simple queries are utterly complicated : filtering on dates, aggregation... All these operations require dynamic SQL, which adds a great deal of complexity
- adding or removing new dates requires modifying the structure of the table
- storage is wasted for rows where not all columns are filled

Instead, consider this simple design, with one table that stores the master data of each `item_sku`, and a child table

```
create table myskus (
    item_sku int primary key,
    name text,
    cat_level_3_name text
);

create table myvalues (
    item_sku int references myskus(item_sku),
    date_sku date,
    value_sku text,
    primary key (item_sku, date_sku)
);
```

Now your original question is easy to solve:

```
select v.*, s.name, s.cat_level_3_name
from myskus s
inner join myvalues v on v.item_sku = s.item_sku
where 
    v.date_sku >= date_trunc('month', now()) 
    and v.date_sku < date_trunc('month', now()) + interval '3 month'
```

Comment: Totally understood your point! But only 16 months data os there in the table and this table is used for updating a google sheet , So thats why came up with this design.But i will surely change the structure as you mentioned.